# Add minutes to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a procedure in PostgreSQL that I want to add the number of minutes to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP like below

timestamp_var := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '20 minutes';

But the number of minutes is a parameter.

Do we have the functions to do this?

Pls help me in this case

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION modify_time(id users.id%TYPE, min integer) AS $$ 
BEGIN
UPDATE
        users
    SET
        modified_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE
        user_id = id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to add **min** minutes to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
thanks

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can multiply intervals by integers. The following gives you a timestamp 20 minutes in the future:

```
select current_timestamp + (20 * interval '1 minute')
```

Or, as **murison** mentions in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21749064/58371) to this question, there is a more succinct way to express this:

```
select current_timestamp + (20 ||' minutes')::interval
```

So, your code could look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION modify_time(id users.id%TYPE, min integer) AS $$ 
BEGIN
UPDATE
        users
    SET
        modified_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + (min * interval '1 minute')
    WHERE
        user_id = id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: thank you in advanced stv, seem it works in Oracle, sorry I'm not asking clearly, I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4, can u help me ?

Comment: I don't know about PostgreSQL, but you should change your question title. PL/SQL is an Oracle-only beast. Perhaps the date math version will work for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Re-did the answer completely. I tested the raw select in Postgres 9.0, but I do not use Postgres every day, so this may not be the best solution.

Comment: UPDATE: "select  '20 minutes'::interval" works fine, at least now-a-days, 5 years later.

Answer (score 46):

the other way is

```
select current_timestamp + (20 ||' minutes')::interval
```

Answer (score 1):

If You need half minute or secounds :

```
SELECT current_timestamp + (50 * interval '1 seconds');
```